# Making A MySQL Database Accesible From Outside The LAN

Tags: mysql-5.6

I am trying to use google apps script to connect to a MySQL database within my local network. I am able to make a connection to a free public database on db4free.net and the code executes just fine so I know I am using the jdbc wrapper and have written the code correctly.

My xampp server is sitting behind a router and 2 levels of switches and I've tried port forwarding to my server (so I can use my public ip address in the script). I've also set the bind-address in the mysql.ini to '0.0.0.0' and have tried granting access to all users (e.g. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {database}.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '{password}'). I've even tried to ensure that the root password contains a capitol letters, numbers, and special characters so that the Google servers don't drop the connection for security reasons (suggestion from a friend). Yet I still get the message: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

I feel that I'm out of options at this point. Is there any thorough documentation out there that describes how to make mysql databases accessible through the internet or should I start digging into how my network is set up at this point?

PS: My xampp server ip is static and I'm using port 3306 for MySQL.

Comment: You need to think about doing this. Exposing your db server to big bad internet has caused one or two problems in the past. Looking at exposing the necessary functionality via a web service would be a better way to go.

Comment: does mysql respond on the ip and port? (using "telnet my.ip.address.here 3306"). Is there more than one root user? I would recommend to add a dedicated user and not use root directly. And have you executed "flush privileges;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work! I re-installed xampp and used the default settings. I followed Wemu's advice on adding a dedicated user. I'll definitely look into a web service but for now I'm just glad I can connect to a database within my network. Thanks for the input guys.